# glUniform fails to set sampler value

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glsl, textures

I'm using OpenGL and GLSL to draw a texture over a simple mesh.

My problem is that when I am using `glUniform1i` to set the value of a sampler2D uniform, it was not set. For example in the in this code:

```
glUseProgram(programObject);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programObject, "texture"), 1);
GLint val;
glGetUniformiv(programObject, 
               glGetUniformLocation(programObject, "texture"), 
               &val);
printf("Value is %d\n", val);
```

The value printed at command line out is 0. I have checked that the shaders are compiled correctly and the program is linked correctly. `glGetUniformLocation` outputs an index > 0. Furthermore, `glGetError` doesn't output any error at any point.

This only happens when the uniform is a sampler. As the texture is not set, quering it in the shader always returns (0, 0, 0, 1). (I have also checked, using [apitrace](https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace), that my texture is correctly bound to `GL_TEXTURE1`, which is done inmediately after the code shown).

I have searched extensively for this problem and I have only found one instance of something similar to this [here](http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about318237.html). The solution was to initialize GLEW, but this hasn't worked for me.

I'm happy to provide any extended info needed (or the trace from apitrace).

**Edit**

Here is the shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

varying vec2 textureCoord;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, textureCoord);
}
```

**Solution**

I managed to solve the problem after some work.

As it turns out, this problem wasn't due to the uniform not being set, as always returning 0 for samplers regardless of actual value appears to be a quirk of the gl implementation. This happened under Intel's driver for Sandy Bridge only. Testing the code under other implementations always returned the correct sampler value.

The problem of the texture returning (0, 0, 0, 1) always was due to a mistake I made during the generation of the texture.

Now the `glGerUniformiv` still returns 0, but the texture used is the correct one.

Comment: You should also post the shader.

Comment: Have you tried naming it something else (texture is also a built-in GLSL function, while not technically a keyword I wouldn't guarantee this will work).

Comment: I tried renaming the uniform to "myTexture" but the result is the same, unfortunately.

Comment: So all shaders compiled and linked successfully to a program? The value of the uniform location or contents of shader/program info logs could give a hint.

Comment: The location of the uniform is 0, and the shader's and program's info log come out empty.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are setting the sampler to 0 and binding the texture to GL_TEXTURE1 rather than GL_TEXTURE0?

Comment: How do you setup texture? Do you build mipmaps?

Comment: What does glGetUniformLocation return?  If it's -1 for some reason, it could explain this behavior.

Comment: Can you post your answer, and accept it so the question doesn't remain open?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

I managed to solve the problem after some work.

As it turns out, this problem wasn't due to the uniform not being set, as always returning 0 for samplers regardless of actual value appears to be a quirk of the gl implementation. This happened under Intel's driver for Sandy Bridge only. Testing the code under other implementations always returned the correct sampler value.

The problem of the texture returning (0, 0, 0, 1) always was due to a mistake I made during the generation of the texture.

Now the glGerUniformiv still returns 0, but the texture used is the correct one.